Nested div and table elements doesn't return values in playwright
I'm working with Playwright and want to catch nested elements and put the values in array.
Trying something like this in my code:
await test.step('Extract table data from HTML', async () => {
    const targetContainer = await page.locator('.new-item-container[style="width: 4190px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"]');
    await targetContainer.waitFor();

    const tableData = await targetContainer.evaluate(container => {
        const tables = container.querySelectorAll('table');
        const data = [];

        tables.forEach(table => {
            const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr');
            const rowData = [];

            rows.forEach(row => {
                const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
                const cellData = [];

                cells.forEach(cell => {
                    cellData.push(cell.innerText.trim());
                });

                rowData.push(cellData);
            });

            data.push(rowData);
        });

Tried to do this directly in the browser and I'm catching them without a problem, but still struggling to make it work in Playwright.

Your code is not returning data.

you are not returning any data in evaluate function ,may be that's an issue try following code.
await test.step('Extract table data from HTML', async () => {
const targetContainer = await page.locator('.new-item-container[style="width: 4190px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"]');
await targetContainer.waitFor();

const tableData = await targetContainer.evaluate(container => {
    const tables = container.querySelectorAll('table');
    const data = [];

    tables.forEach(table => {
        const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr');
        const rowData = [];

        rows.forEach(row => {
            const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
            const cellData = [];

            cells.forEach(cell => {
                cellData.push(cell.textContent.trim());
            });

            rowData.push(cellData);
        });

        data.push(rowData);
    });

    return data;
});
});

